# populate Vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am working on populate_vector function in C++ 
As I am a newbie in C++ language, it is quite difficult to get into vector concept.

- What I want to do is get x, y for input(which is above but not showing here) and have (3x * 2y) size vectors. And fill the vectors with the random numbers for representing a trio of pixels, (red, green, blue)
- a 1-dimensional array to represent a 2-dimensional matrix

The question is: 
The code does not work properly. When I run it, it just shows the input entered code and then when entering the input, then that's it. I dont know why it does not work and how to change it

```
    vector<int> xVector((3*x) * (2*y));
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    //  int a = rand() % 255 +1;


    for (int i = 0; i < xVector.size(); i++)
    {
    int b = rand() % 255 + 1;
    int c = rand() % 255 + 1;

    xVector.push_back(b);
    xVector.push_back(c);
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < xVector.size(); i++)
    {
      cout << "xVector[" << i << "] : " << xVector[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: The question is above there

Comment: No it's not. You're saying what you want to do, then you're posting some code. Is there a problem with the code? Does it not do what you want it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: If you want a 2-dimensional matrix, then use a vector of vectors. Do not use a hammer when you need a wrench.

Comment: Why "3x * 2y"?  What are x and y?  Is it a two-dimensional vector with size x in one dimension, and size y in another dimension, and additionally you have ... 6 sub-values per cell?  Maybe it would be better to have vector<struct> and not do that logic in the vector indexing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @Daniel, when you say you "edited" a question, your comment should highlight what you changed. If you want help, be helpful.

Comment: I switched the for loop to int i = 0; i < xVector.size(); i++

Answer (score 2):

You iterate the vector, and in each element you add two more. so it is a never ending loop.

the `.push_back` will add at the end of the vector that element, so `size()` is always increasing.

I would suggest something like this.

```
vector<int> xVector((3*x) * (2*y));
std::generate(xVector.begin(), xVector.end(), []{return rand() % 255 + 1;});
```

or if you want to use a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < xVector.size(); ++i){
     xVector[i] = rand() % 255 + 1;
}
```

it will set a random number for each element.

Comment: When I use it, it shows an error of the expression while compiling.

Comment: right, i forgot a ; try it now. you can check it is working here http://cpp.sh/6vkt3

Comment: I like how this sidesteps the questions about the vector indexing.We don't care; just plug in values anyway. +1 But this does show a complete lack of effort by the OP, not even running the code in a debugger.  I'd add #include <algorithm> and maybe use a named function to generate the random color data, because the 255 range has actual meaning.

Comment: I am using it from atom editor but says . cpp:25:49: error: expected expression
std::generate(xVector.begin(), xVector.end(), []{return srand() % 255 + 1;});
^

Comment: @KennyOstrom what do you mean, the main problem of the question was answered, it did not work correctly because it would add elements at end of the array so size will increase, thus a never ending loop, as to my solution, that's my personal taste, there is many ways to populate a vector.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a `vector` of `struct`.
Example:

```
struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
};
std::vector<Point> database;
```

Maybe you want a 2d container of pixel attributes:

```
struct Pixel
{
  unsigned int red;
  unsigned int green;
  unsigned int blue;
};
std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> > bitmap;
```

Using a vector (or array), where odd entries are X and even entries are Y, is just plain messy.  Parallel arrays are difficult to maintain and lead to a lot of defects.

The better solutions involve using arrays or vectors of structures.